# Android Build/Progard logs under Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, export, proguard

I have been building Adroid apps for a while now, but have always been using the ANT Command Line model to build the release versions.

I have decided to use the eclispe EXPORT model to begin building my android release APK's and it appears to be working.

However, as nice as this is, I don't see the logs from the build anywhere, so I am not sure that the PROGUARD part of the build actually worked.  The APK is created, and it appears signed, but I'd feel more comfortable to be able to actually see the build output, particularly the proguard steps that would normally be part of the console output when building with ANT.

I open a console window in Eclipse when I select export and see nothing, and when I try to find information on the build logging for Eclipse with Android I equally find nothing.

Where are the sysout/build logs from the export commands written?

Comment: I don't think PROGUARD is working properly, I intentionally mess up the proguard.cfg and I see output in the console.  However if I make sure there are no errors, the build happens, but the file assigned by -printmapping never gets created anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

By using the normal Ant configuration dialogs and then running the normal targets for ( Clean, Debug ) , i see the DX output right in the eclipse console tab... You would have the same general experience with target=release and proguard step within that process..

1. Eclipse / external tools config
2. tab=targets - select the targets you want included ( clean, debug )
3. verify the target execution order
4. run ant and look at the console....

you will see proguard where dx is shown below if u run the release target.

eclipse console:

```
       [dx] associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
       [dx] compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
       [dx] solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
       [dx] and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
       [dx] this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
       [dx] indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
       [dx] warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
       [dx] (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
       [dx] associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
       [dx] compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
       [dx] solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
       [dx] and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
       [dx] this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
       [dx] indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
       [dx] 2 warnings
-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache
-package-resources:
     [aapt] Current build type is different than previous build: forced aapt run.
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...
-package:
     [echo] --apk outfldr:C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin  resourcefile: gpsclipper.ap_
     [echo]             apkfilepath: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin\gpsclipper-debug-unaligned.apk  verbose: false
     [echo]              Dxpath: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin\classes.dex
     [echo]              srcFldrPth: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\src jarRFID: ${project.libraries.jars} 
     [echo]             nativeFldr: ${project.libraries.libs}
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating gpsclipper-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
-post-package:
-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin\gpsclipper-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin\build.prop
-post-build:
debug:
-pre-clean:
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\bin
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\cygwin\home\rob\src\gpsclipper\gen
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 54 seconds
```

Comment: Robert, thank you for the answer, but I am trying not to define my own explicite ANT call, just see the output that is being generated by the built in export execution.  When I navigate to the run->external_tools->external tools config there is no configuration visible for ANT.  I really don't want to explicitely define the ant command, just see the output for the one that export android is executing.

Comment: Well I still haven't found the explicite logs, but do see the MAPPINGS files being generated so I guess I will just rely on that as proof that proguard ran properly.

Comment: @user282172 i haven't been able to see Proguard logs until i configured my projects to be built using ant. To me that's the only way to see proguard logs in the console.

Answer (score 0):

within the workspace that holds the project information you will find a directory called Proguard, this directory holds all the build logs and mapping that will give you the information as to what was done and what are the results.